# Why does Java's URL class not recognize certain protocols?

Tags: java, url, protocols, malformedurlexception

```
URL u=new URL("telnet://route-server.exodus.net");
```

This line is generating :

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: telnet
```

And I encounter similar problems with other URLs that begin with "news://"

These are URLs extracted from ODP, so I don't understand why such exceptions arise..

Comment: Thanks to all , learnt something new ..

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## Issue

Java throws a `MalformedURLException` because it couldn't find a `URLStreamHandler` for that protocol. Check the [javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) of the constructors for the details.

## Summary

Since the `URL` class has an `openConnection` method, the URL class checks to make sure that Java knows how to open a connection of the correct protocol. Without a `URLStreamHandler` for that protocol, Java refuses to create a `URL` to save you from failure when you try to call `openConnection`.

## Solution

You should probably be using the [`URI`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class if you don't plan on opening a connection of those protocols in Java.

Comment: or, one may implement his own URLStreamHandler

Comment: Thanks a lot. URI class is the solution for me.

Comment: Can I still send data (using URI)?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like there's no registered handler for the protocol "telnet" in your application. Since the URL class can be used to open a InputStream to URL it needs to have a registered handler for the protocol to do this work if you're to be allowed to create an object using it.

For details on how to add handlers see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandlerFactory.html

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because java doesn't have a standard [protocol handler](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/protocolhandlers/) for telnet.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that it only *does* recognize certain protocols, and the remainder of the infinity of protocols is not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

If the image URL begins with "data", it means that the image data is embedded in the HTML page itself, rather than being stored on a remote server that can be accessed via a URL. Therefore, you cannot download the image using a standard HTTP connection. So, the base64 mechanism helps us.

Image Source URL : data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAWAUNoinFRBWASIUA........AAAAElFTkSuQmCC

To download the image, the below code can be used:

```
// Get the image source data
String imageData = webElement.getAttribute("src");

// Extract the image data and file extension from the data URL
String[] parts = imageData.split(",");
String mimeType = parts[0].split(":")[1];
String base64Data = parts[1];
String fileExtension = "";

if (mimeType.equals("image/jpeg")) {
    fileExtension = ".jpg";
} else if (mimeType.equals("image/png")) {
    fileExtension = ".png";
} else if (mimeType.equals("image/gif")) {
    fileExtension = ".gif";
} else {
    // Unsupported image format
    throw new IOException("Unsupported image format");
}

// Set the output file path and stream. Here, we save the image file.
String outputPath = "C:/images/image" + fileExtension;
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);

// Close the output stream
outputStream.close();
```

This code first extracts the image data from the "data" URL and splits it into its MIME type and base64-encoded data components. It then determines the file extension based on the MIME type and saves the image to a file on disk, after decoding the base64-encoded image data. Note that you will need to handle any exceptions that may occur during the decoding and file I/O processes.

To use this code, you will need to import the following classes in addition to the ones I mentioned in my previous answer:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Base64;
```

The java.util.Base64 class is used to decode the base64-encoded image data. The java.io.File class is used to represent the output file on disk.

I hope this might help someone!