# How to parse URL if protocol is not http or https?

Tags: java, url

My question is how to parse url where protocol is different?

```
String str = "olqmeeting://192.168.43.55/uam/meeting/meeting.php?id=A72U5AF9";
URL url = new URL(str);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parse URL"? If there isn't an `URLStreamHandler` that knows how to process the `olqmeeting` protocol, you'll get a `MalformedURLException` for an unknown protocol.

Comment: its working :
URI url = new URI( "olqmeeting"+"://"+serverName+"/uam/meeting/meeting.php?type="+type);
   
   System.out.println("Scheme: "+url.getScheme());
   System.out.println("HostName: "+url.getHost())

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `URI` class to parse those URLs.  It will work ... though you are limited to operations on the URL itself, no on the resource that it refers to.  (Refer to the `URI` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) for more details.)

If you want `URL` to work (and to be able to "connect" to the resource), then you need to implement and configure a `URLStreamHandlerFactory` that (minimally) understands the URL's protocol and how to handle it.

(If you don't supply a non-null `URLStreamHandlerFactory` explicitly when you create the `URL` object, the constructor will attempt to find the default one for the URL's protocol.  If it can't do that, you get a `MalformedURLException`.)

Answer (score 0):

URL has other constructors where you can define the protocol

```
URL(String protocol, String host, int port, String file)
Creates a URL object from the specified protocol, host, port number, and file.
URL(String protocol, String host, int port, String file, URLStreamHandler handler)
Creates a URL object from the specified protocol, host, port number, file, and handler.
URL(String protocol, String host, String file)
Creates a URL from the specified protocol name, host name, and file name.
```

Eventually you can even use the `.set()` method but it is protected so you need to implement a new custom URL class

Comment: when trying to parse to get hostname and to get protocol its giving  a MalformedURLException for an unknown protocol.Can i make custom protocol??

Comment: @SalikReza see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363573/registering-and-using-a-custom-java-net-url-protocol