# What protocols does FileUtils.copyUrlToFile support?

Tags: java, network-programming, apache-commons, network-protocols

what are the protocols that commons-io FileUtils.copyUrlToFile allow to copy from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: It depends on the JVM, but at least `http`, `https`, `file`, and `jar` will work.

**Long answer**: FileUils uses Java's `java.net.URL` to handle the actual connection. `java.net.url` uses protocol-specific instances of [URLStreamHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html) to implement different protocol. The handlers are found dynamically, and you can [add your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363573/registering-and-using-a-custom-java-net-url-protocol). According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html), you are guaranteed to have http, https, file and jar handlers:

> Protocol handlers for the following protocols are guaranteed to exist
>   on the search path :-
>
> http, https, file, and jar

Handlers for other protocols are not guaranteed to exist on every JVM. On my Windows x64 machine, which uses Java 8u111, under `sun.net.www.protocol` I also see `mailto`, `ftp` and `netdoc` handlers, which means that these protocols are supported. Note that the fact that a protocol is supported, doesn't mean that `copyUrlToFile` makes sense for it (e.g. mailto)