# How to launch the desktop application from a browser and pass the parameters to it using java?

Tags: java, url-routing, desktop-application

I need to launch my desktop java application from our website and I need to pass parameters to it.The desktop application will handle the parameters.  I don't know how to implement it. I checked java web-start,But in that we need to download the .jnlp file everytime. So I'm avoiding java-web-start.
I have seen this feature in skype, Gotomeeting etc.

**Edit:**
As suggested by @Marged I created the custom URL handler in my application using java. Followed this link: [Registering and using a custom java.net.URL protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363573/registering-and-using-a-custom-java-net-url-protocol) 
It's working if i register the URL handler Manually. Now I need to register the URL handler for my application programmaticalley using java.I need to register the URL handler with windows and Mac os. The code below is for windows I think.

How to run this code in java?Please help me..

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/
myprotocol/
(Default)    "URL:myprotocol Protocol"
URL Protocol ""
shell/
  open/
    command/
      (Default) "c:/users/MyApplication.exe"
```

Comment: You could make your desktop application install an URL handler

Comment: Hi @Marged As you suggested, I created a custom URL handler using java in my application. But I'm not getting how to register the URL Handler programmaticalley using java.Please help me..