# Compile Java class in runtime with dependencies to nested jar

Tags: spring-boot, java-compiler-api, runtime-compilation, javacompiler

In a Spring Boot app I'm doing the following at runtime:

1. Generating a Java class
2. Compiling it
3. Accessing some static fields of the compiled class using reflection.

I've based my code on [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200112191828/http://www.beyondlinux.com/2011/07/20/3-steps-to-dynamically-compile-instantiate-and-run-a-java-class/) and got a problem compiling my generated class in runtime. When running in the IDE compilation works just fine but when running from a Spring Boot jar compilation fails saying symbols are missing or some package does not exist. The class I'm compiling has dependencies to other classes that reside in a jar under `\BOOT-INF\lib\` and it seems the compiler fails to load those classes using the existing class loader.

I've followed [this post](https://atamur.blogspot.com/2009/10/using-built-in-javacompiler-with-custom.html) which suppose to address this specific problem but I got `UnsupportedOperationException` coming from method

```
default Iterable<Set<Location>> listLocationsForModules(Location location) throws IOException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

of interface `JavaFileManager`.

I've encountered another possible solution given [here](https://www.jppf.org/forums/index.php?topic=7668.0) but I'm not clear exactly with the full implementation.

This seems like a well known issue when compiling a class in runtime, is there any clear solution for that?

I'm currently using Java 10.0.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you haven't mentioned it explicitly I think you are running a version of Java with [modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) (JDK 9+), but the guides you have been following are for earlier versions starting from Java 6. This is why you are getting the error about unsupported `listLocationsForModules` because the JDK developers retrofitted the `FileManager` with with default methods that throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

If you don't actually want to use a version of Java greater than 8, I would stick with JDK8 it will be much easier!

I'll continue assuming you do want to use Java 9 and above (tested my code in Java 11) however:

For handling modules it is sufficient your file manager to delegate to the standard file manager:

```
@Override
public Location getLocationForModule(Location location, String moduleName) throws IOException {
    return standardFileManager.getLocationForModule(location, moduleName);
}

@Override
public Location getLocationForModule(Location location, JavaFileObject fo) throws IOException {
    return standardFileManager.getLocationForModule(location, fo);
}

@Override
public Iterable<Set<Location>> listLocationsForModules(Location location) throws IOException {
    return standardFileManager.listLocationsForModules(location);
}

@Override
public String inferModuleName(Location location) throws IOException {
    return standardFileManager.inferModuleName(location);
}
```

I also found it necessary to modify Atamur's code to check explicitly for the base java module (so that we can resolve java.lang in Java 9+!) and delegate to the standard file manager as you would have for the platform class path in previous versions:

```
@Override
public Iterable<JavaFileObject> list(Location location, String packageName, Set<JavaFileObject.Kind> kinds, boolean recurse) throws IOException {
    boolean baseModule = location.getName().equals("SYSTEM_MODULES[java.base]");
    if (baseModule || location == StandardLocation.PLATFORM_CLASS_PATH) { // **MODIFICATION CHECK FOR BASE MODULE**
        return standardFileManager.list(location, packageName, kinds, recurse);
    } else if (location == StandardLocation.CLASS_PATH && kinds.contains(JavaFileObject.Kind.CLASS)) {
        if (packageName.startsWith("java") || packageName.startsWith("com.sun")) {
            return standardFileManager.list(location, packageName, kinds, recurse);
        } else { // app specific classes are here
            return finder.find(packageName);
        }
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();

}
```

### *Updates*

Some other points:

Extracting embedded spring boot classes:

Get the jarUri by looking for the last index of '!' in each packageFolderURL as in [Taeyun Kim's comment](https://atamur.blogspot.com/2009/10/using-built-in-javacompiler-with-custom.html?showComment=1431689463135#c8013606759010813870) and not the first as in the original example.

```
 private List<JavaFileObject> processJar(URL packageFolderURL) {
  List<JavaFileObject> result = new ArrayList<JavaFileObject>();
  try {
    // Replace:
    // String jarUri = packageFolderURL.toExternalForm().split("!")[0];
    // With:
    String externalForm = packageFolderURL.toExternalForm();
    String jarUri = externalForm.substring(0, externalForm.lastIndexOf('!'));


    JarURLConnection jarConn = (JarURLConnection) packageFolderURL.openConnection();
    String rootEntryName = jarConn.getEntryName();
    int rootEnd = rootEntryName.length()+1;
    // ...
```

This allows package `PackageInternalsFinder` to return `CustomJavaFileObject` with full URIs to classes in embedded spring jars (under `BOOT-INF/lib`) which are then resolved with [spring boot jar URI handler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/Handler.java#L41) which is registered in similar way to as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409796/1900169). The URI handling should just happen automatically through spring boot.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using Java 10 so I guess you're solution does not apply to me? I might consider upgrading to 11

Comment: This answer should apply to Java 9 through to 11. So my answer should apply in your case. There should be no need to upgrade to Java 11.

Comment: Are you positive it doesn't fit java 10? should I give it a shot?

Comment: It **is** worth a shot. There should be no problem! I modified my answer to make it clear it will work on Java 9+.

Comment: Great, will give it a shot soon

Comment: With your proposal compilation still fails, now with the following message: >cannot access org.web3j.abi.TypeReference
  bad class file: file:/C:/dev/project-folder/maven-parent/My-Project/target/App-spring-boot.jar!/org/web3j/abi/TypeReference.class
    unable to access file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry org/web3j/abi/TypeReference.class not found in C:\dev\project-folder\maven-parent\My-Project\target\App-spring-boot.jar
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.]

Comment: TypeReference  is a class I'm using in the class I'm compiling, it resides in a jar called abi-3.5.0.jar. spring boot executable jar wraps this jar in path C:\dev\project-folder\maven-parent\My-Project\target\App-spring-boot.jar\BOOT-INF\lib\abi-3.5.0.jar

Comment: Its the responsibility of `PackageInternalsFinder.processJar` to produce a `CustomJavaFileObject` for each class in embedded spring boot dependency. A commenter Atamur's article (Taeyun Kim) offers a solution that will enable it produce objects for spring boot. Did you apply it?

Comment: Yes I'm almost sure you haven't applied the fix because the error references `C:/dev/project-folder/maven-parent/My-Project/target/App-spring-boot.jar!/org/web3j/abi/TypeReference.class` whereas the full path to the class is `C:/dev/project-folder/maven-parent/My-Project/target/App-spring-boot.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/abi-3.5.0!/org/web3j/abi/TypeReference.class`. If you chop it at the last `!` not the first it will retain the full path to the embedded JAR.

Comment: It works, in PackageInternalsFinder.processJar, I changed how the jar path is extracted:             int endIndex = packageFolderURL.toExternalForm().lastIndexOf("!");
            String jarUri = packageFolderURL.toExternalForm().substring(0, endIndex);