# Batik SVG parsing with inline base64 images in JasperReports

Tags: svg, jasper-reports, batik

I have been trying for hours to parse the following .svg file (Which works fine on "Inkscape") using the Batik renderer in JasperReports (though I don't know if this is mainly a batik problem or not)

I am using Batik 1.13 and JasperReports 6.13 with it's "net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.SimpleDataRenderer". This Renderer uses Batik.

I get the following errorcode when trying to render a file with base64 images:

> java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
> at com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Unknown Source)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.processImageRetainShape(JRPdfExporter.java:1992)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.process(JRPdfExporter.java:1787)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.access$300(JRPdfExporter.java:1713)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportImage(JRPdfExporter.java:1653)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:1267)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:1210)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:1074)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:691)
> at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.export(ReportCommand.java:192)
> at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.export(ReportCommand.java:159)
> at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportManager.generateReportToStream(ReportManager.java:175)
> at enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports.service.CdoReportService.generateReportToStream(CdoReportService.java:87)
> at enco.sox2.workspace.cdo.server.internal.CreateReportIndication.responding(CreateReportIndication.java:103)
> at org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.internal.net4j.protocol.CDOServerIndicationWithMonitoring.responding(CDOServerIndicationWithMonitoring.java:177)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithMonitoring.responding(IndicationWithMonitoring.java:93)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithResponse.doExtendedOutput(IndicationWithResponse.java:106)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.doOutput(Signal.java:346)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithResponse.execute(IndicationWithResponse.java:75)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithMonitoring.execute(IndicationWithMonitoring.java:66)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.runSync(Signal.java:283)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.run(Signal.java:162)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> 18:01:22,388 ERROR [ReportCommand] An error occured exporting to java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.processImageRetainShape(JRPdfExporter.java:1997)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.process(JRPdfExporter.java:1787)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.access$300(JRPdfExporter.java:1713)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportImage(JRPdfExporter.java:1653)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:1267)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:1210)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:1074)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:691)
> at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.export(ReportCommand.java:192)
> at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.export(ReportCommand.java:159)
> at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportManager.generateReportToStream(ReportManager.java:175)
> at enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports.service.CdoReportService.generateReportToStream(CdoReportService.java:87)
> at enco.sox2.workspace.cdo.server.internal.CreateReportIndication.responding(CreateReportIndication.java:103)
> at org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.internal.net4j.protocol.CDOServerIndicationWithMonitoring.responding(CDOServerIndicationWithMonitoring.java:177)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithMonitoring.responding(IndicationWithMonitoring.java:93)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithResponse.doExtendedOutput(IndicationWithResponse.java:106)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.doOutput(Signal.java:346)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithResponse.execute(IndicationWithResponse.java:75)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithMonitoring.execute(IndicationWithMonitoring.java:66)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.runSync(Signal.java:283)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.run(Signal.java:162)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
> at com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Unknown Source)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.processImageRetainShape(JRPdfExporter.java:1992)
> ... 23 more
> [ERROR] net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
> !ENTRY enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports 4 0 2020-08-14 18:01:22.390
> !MESSAGE net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
> !STACK 0
> enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
> at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.export(ReportCommand.java:195)
> at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.export(ReportCommand.java:159)
> at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportManager.generateReportToStream(ReportManager.java:175)
> at enco.sox2.cdo.server.reports.service.CdoReportService.generateReportToStream(CdoReportService.java:87)
> at enco.sox2.workspace.cdo.server.internal.CreateReportIndication.responding(CreateReportIndication.java:103)
> at org.eclipse.emf.cdo.server.internal.net4j.protocol.CDOServerIndicationWithMonitoring.responding(CDOServerIndicationWithMonitoring.java:177)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithMonitoring.responding(IndicationWithMonitoring.java:93)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithResponse.doExtendedOutput(IndicationWithResponse.java:106)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.doOutput(Signal.java:346)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithResponse.execute(IndicationWithResponse.java:75)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.IndicationWithMonitoring.execute(IndicationWithMonitoring.java:66)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.runSync(Signal.java:283)
> at org.eclipse.net4j.signal.Signal.run(Signal.java:162)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.processImageRetainShape(JRPdfExporter.java:1997)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.process(JRPdfExporter.java:1787)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.access$300(JRPdfExporter.java:1713)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportImage(JRPdfExporter.java:1653)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:1267)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:1210)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:1074)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:691)
> at enco.sox2.reportmanager.ReportCommand.export(ReportCommand.java:192)
> ... 15 more
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.
> at com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(Unknown Source)
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter$InternalImageProcessor.processImageRetainShape(JRPdfExporter.java:1992)
> ... 23 more

Here the .svg File for reference.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN'
          'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd'>
<svg fill-opacity="1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" color-rendering="auto" color-interpolation="auto" text-rendering="auto" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="square" width="1000" stroke-miterlimit="10" shape-rendering="auto" stroke-opacity="1" fill="black" stroke-dasharray="none" font-weight="normal" stroke-width="1" height="385" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" font-family="&apos;Dialog&apos;" font-style="normal" stroke-linejoin="miter" font-size="12" stroke-dashoffset="0" image-rendering="auto"
><!--Generated by the Batik Graphics2D SVG Generator--><defs id="genericDefs"
  /><g
  ><defs id="defs1"
    ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath1"
      ><path d="M659 58 L701 58 L701 91 L659 91 L659 58 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath2"
      ><path d="M659 88 L701 88 L701 121 L659 121 L659 88 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath3"
      ><path d="M319 88 L361 88 L361 91 L319 91 L319 88 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath4"
      ><path d="M19 52 L321 52 L321 128 L19 128 L19 52 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath5"
      ><path d="M24 57 L38 57 L38 89 L24 89 L24 57 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath6"
      ><path d="M-1 -8 L9 -8 L9 24 L-1 24 L-1 -8 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath7"
      ><path d="M-1 -8 L17 -8 L17 24 L-1 24 L-1 -8 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath8"
      ><path d="M55 57 L289 57 L289 89 L55 89 L55 57 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath9"
      ><path d="M298 57 L316 57 L316 89 L298 89 L298 57 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath10"
      ><path d="M24 87 L316 87 L316 123 L24 123 L24 87 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath11"
      ><path d="M26 89 L40 89 L40 121 L26 121 L26 89 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath12"
      ><path d="M54 89 L297 89 L297 121 L54 121 L54 89 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath13"
      ><path d="M699 39 L1001 39 L1001 81 L699 81 L699 39 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath14"
      ><path d="M704 44 L718 44 L718 76 L704 76 L704 44 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath15"
      ><path d="M735 44 L991 44 L991 76 L735 76 L735 44 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath16"
      ><path d="M699 99 L1001 99 L1001 141 L699 141 L699 99 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath17"
      ><path d="M704 104 L718 104 L718 136 L704 136 L704 104 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath18"
      ><path d="M735 104 L985 104 L985 136 L735 136 L735 104 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath19"
      ><path d="M359 69 L661 69 L661 111 L359 111 L359 69 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath20"
      ><path d="M364 74 L378 74 L378 106 L364 106 L364 74 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath21"
      ><path d="M395 74 L632 74 L632 106 L395 106 L395 74 Z"
      /></clipPath
      ><clipPath clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="clipPath22"
      ><path d="M638 74 L656 74 L656 106 L638 106 L638 74 Z"
      /></clipPath
    ></defs
    ><g fill="silver" font-family="&apos;Segoe UI&apos;" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke="silver"
    ><line y2="59" fill="none" x1="660" clip-path="url(#clipPath1)" x2="699" y1="89"
      /><line y2="119" fill="none" x1="660" clip-path="url(#clipPath2)" x2="699" y1="89"
      /><line y2="89" fill="none" x1="320" clip-path="url(#clipPath3)" x2="359" y1="89"
      /><rect x="20" y="53" clip-path="url(#clipPath4)" fill="white" width="300" rx="4" ry="4" height="74" stroke="none"
      /><rect x="20" y="53" clip-path="url(#clipPath4)" fill="none" width="299" rx="4" ry="4" height="73" stroke="black"
      /><rect x="25" y="58" clip-path="url(#clipPath5)" fill="white" width="12" height="30" stroke="none"
      /><image x="0" y="0" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,27,65)" clip-path="url(#clipPath6)" fill="white" width="8" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAQCAYAAAArij59AAAAXklEQVR42mP8//8/
Az7AxEAADFoFBw4c+N/Z2fkfq4J9+/b9z8nJYZg3bx6mCSDJvLw8Bl1dXUwrkCUZ
GRlRFeCSBAEWEHH69GmG379/M5w7dw4ukZCQAKYZB0FcAADWfSpLwQBSHgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" height="16" stroke="white" preserveAspectRatio="none"
      /><rect x="27" y="58" clip-path="url(#clipPath5)" fill="none" width="7" height="29" stroke="black"
      /><image x="0" y="0" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,37,65)" clip-path="url(#clipPath7)" fill="black" width="16" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAACq0lEQVR42pWTXUhT
YRjH/+/Z2dnmx5riMKeVJUsoTcsSJENliWAXeWFU0EUgBEFREEVfN14UDEESpGAZ
JF1ESoiEZk3TmoXkB1oZ5pxihLra3If7cOfM83YWDuZAof/dec///J7/85znJViX
6DYVI7hUTQPzCqxYB2SFH94gTgsNXG1a+ZkTjDoThFOBhoUu8u9j56MbxG25D8+g
DGEfQAn8Tp/J8Tt0Mfs8xChg6BIe5B5Mv6JQawCFGiBMEyvajcXE1WP8PJKAzvF6
iCJF+Z4ulGa8vLC4SD5JtNYoIMQjKCzbwQXsgCoJNCE1yFDfbA1cAxj/lY+xmcwI
Fab+U2BZwG6ntbEthAWIgQDgkkJ6PTzWfB4VC980h7AXCjaMZb8G1j/JyM14ByZS
0aPOpi8e10G3o/fqE5O/eeZjSenSQuNulX+FYXnoc/hBlnomzSD0WsDvh2HXM5ws
mUTD6zpMTBLo51Py0Nragqoqhz5Na+v/rjN2WKwdsalkl6uDs/ZF6HTcSNGx3FFo
lbPIEnvgMgs4anGDmbYCw8MJRwoOpJ7dm3PdaLH4NgAa2imaOvGqbGfYNj21RqeG
6Yq2V8g6PiG9jM4/GATxeORKt/tr/dzcRCyAxP/rFqCsGBjIX3+mUZNcLg1ROC0H
2mL9TDxgWQo8CnxxxlQQIkvEcQ5bQWF3vF8Wf2CW/EXAextwOARkRUA/gLGH+/Ns
gTt3A93tbd+2bCGqW1I6aRUOSTsnSwFGm7enJ9cUZXTcPFchUo2WEmUiqMA/3wCo
qKwk/WYz3Qz6tkR1b58+7bYiKREkSQOGUzZumAEjisRgMGyaimVYRgxJjXkdgM8F
8EGejTX09fWJ2EIBnsoXnAI4OYHM60LKtlU5i/9QiBeHftpXnzJSRlYav3Sdh/4C
CCwZRQKg7fwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" height="16" stroke="black" preserveAspectRatio="none"
      />
    ></g
  ></g
></svg
>
```

If anyone has any idea I'd be delighted to hear it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The SVG fails to render because Batik relies on `java.net.URL` to load embedded images, and the `data:` scheme is not supported out of the box in Java.

To have the SVG render, you'll need to add a `URLStreamHandler` implementation for the `data:` scheme, and register it via the `java.protocol.handler.pkgs` system property.

The URL handler can use for instance [jdatauri](https://github.com/ooxi/jdatauri) (you can also find [on Maven](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.ooxi/jdatauri)).

To register it, you'll need to run Java with `-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=net.myself.handlers`

```
package net.myself.handlers.data;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import com.github.ooxi.jdatauri.DataUri;

public class Handler extends URLStreamHandler {
    public Handler() {
    }

    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {
        DataUri dataUri = DataUri.parse(u.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] data = dataUri.getData();
        return new URLConnection(u) {
            @Override
            public void connect() {             
            }

            @Override
            public InputStream getInputStream() {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and added a "public class DataUriHandler extends URLStreamHandler {" based on your advice, but  after adding `-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=my.path.handlers` to my launch configs it still wouldnt load that data Handler. I am by no means an expert with url connections (quite the opposite) so do I need to do more? I read that there is more to be done according to [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363573/registering-and-using-a-custom-java-net-url-protocol) but I don't quite understand it. Thank you!

Comment: You can do some reading at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-java.lang.String-
The class name needs to be Handler and the class package should be my.path.handlers.data