# Is it possible to programmatically provide a Java KeyStore and TrustStore to Connector/J?

Tags: jdbc, keystore, mysql-connector

I'd like to connect to a MySQL/MariaDB RDBMS using Connector/J (or another compatible driver) and provide the keystore and truststore *directly* to the driver, rather than supplying a filename for an on-disk keystore/truststore.

I'm not storing my keys and certificates on the disk any longer and I'd like to avoid having to drop them into a temporary file just for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I think it *is* possible, if you are willing to go through a log of hoops to make it happen.

Because e.g. `clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl` will accept a **URL**, you can supply it one with a *custom protocol handler*, like `mykeysupplier://mykey`.

You can [write a custom `URLConnection` class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409796/276232) for `mekeysupplier` and then return whatever bytes you want from the `getInputStream()` method. You have to register a protocol handler and stuff like that, too.

So, it's kind of horrifically ugly, but I think it can be made to work and will surely try at least a PoC of this idea, because it will likely solve my problem (I posted the original question).

Answer (score 1):

This answer seems to be **no**. As the way to [configure](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/core-api/java/com/mysql/cj/conf/PropertyKey.java#L92) KeyStore and TrustStore is by providing an URL, not a class/factory.

Answer (score 1):

There may be another option.

I re-read the [configuration reference for Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) and there is a URL property that can be specified for connections:  `socketFactory`. This must be the fully-qualified name of a class which implements Connector/J's interface called `SocketFactory` (note that this is similar but unrelated to the standard library class `javax.net.SocketFactory`).

This interface is pretty small:

```
public interface SocketFaactory {
    Socket afterHandshake() throws SocketException, IOException;
    Socket beforeHandshake() throws SocketException, IOException;
    Socket connect(String host, int portNumber, Properties props) throws SocketException, IOException;
}
```

Later versions of the driver add a fourth `int loginTimeout` parameter to the `connect` method.

At any rate, it looks like this might be the basis for a solution.

Unfortunately, MySQL does not use vanilla TLS connections so it might not be as simple as returning a Socket from a standard customized `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`.

***UPDATE***

The SSL/TLS magic happens after connection due to the way MySQL manages its protocol (it's not just plain-TLS).

In the 5.1-era drivers, it's done in a class called `ExportControlled` in a method called `getSSLSocketFactoryDefaultOrConfigured`. In later versions (I have 8.0-era source in front of me), it's done in the same class but in a different method called `performTlsHandshake`.

Without significant hacking of the driver source or re-implementation of a ton of code, I suspect that the better solution is to implement the URL-based keystore-loading from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75367366/276232).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's possible to programmatically provide a Java KeyStore and TrustStore to Connector/J. You can use the `java.security.KeyStore` and `java.security.TrustStore` classes to create the keystore and truststore in memory, and then pass them to the Connector/J `Driver` and `Connection` classes via the `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` system properties, respectively.
HERE IS A CODE SAMPLE

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;

// ...

// Load the keystore and truststore data into memory
byte[] keystoreData = ...;
byte[] truststoreData = ...;

// Create the keystore and truststore objects
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyStore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(keystoreData), keystorePassword);
trustStore.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(truststoreData), truststorePassword);

// Set the system properties to use the in-memory keystore and truststore
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", keyStore);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStore);

// Connect to the database using Connector/J
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code is wrong. It won't even compile because `System.setProperty` only takes String values. Add to that the fact that hijacking the JVM-wide default trust store and key store is a Really Bad Idea.