# how to add custom url protocol handlers in java 17

Tags: java, java-17

In java 17 not able to use reflection to add the custom url protocol handlers.

Below code was perfectly fine before jdk 17 but after upgrading to jdk17 not working while trying to add custom url handler

It is throwing below exception in jdk 17.

> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field static java.util.Hashtable java.net.URL.handlers accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @2ed0fbae

```
private void addHandler() {
        logger.info("adding " + Handler.class + " as URL handler for: " + PROTOCOL);
        Field urlHandlersField = null;
        try {
            urlHandlersField = URL.class.getDeclaredField("handlers");
            urlHandlersField.setAccessible(true);
            Hashtable<String, URLStreamHandler> urlHandlers = null;
            urlHandlers = (Hashtable<String, URLStreamHandler>) urlHandlersField.get(urlHandlers);
            if (urlHandlers == null) {
                urlHandlers = new Hashtable<String, URLStreamHandler>();
            }
            
            urlHandlers.put(PROTOCOL, new Handler());
           
            urlHandlersField.set(null, urlHandlers);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            logger.error("Failed to add " + Handler.class + " as URL handler for: " + PROTOCOL, t);
        } finally {
            if (urlHandlersField != null) {
                urlHandlersField.setAccessible(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

How to add custom url protocol handlers in jdk17 along with existing default url handlers without using reflection?

Comment: Tried register it during application's startup via 

URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new CustomURLStreamHandlerFactory());
Note that the Javadoc explicitly says that you can set it at most once.

But when i start wildfly server to bring up the application the custom url handler registration is failing as factory is already defined.

Comment: Have you tried the `java.protocol.handler.pkgs` system property, as described on https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html? According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46619972/1180351 you can even change it dynamically.

Comment: “Below code was perfectly fine before jdk 17” No, it wasn’t. You were messing with internals that were private *for a reason.*  It was never okay to do that, and Java warned people for years that internal implementations can change without notice.  There have always been public, approved ways to register URL protocol handlers, which didn’t involve hacking Java SE classes.

Comment: yes , tried with java.protocol.handler.pkgs system property but still not able to find the handler for the custom protocol

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work with Java 17 is that it now uses more strict security. You can override that by adding the following option to your `java` command line:

```
--add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
```

However, this is not recommended. The way you are adding a protocol handler was never the right way, as it has always depended on undocumented internals of the URL class which could have changed without notice any day.

One way to add a protocol handler is by calling the static method [setURLStreamHandlerFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory(java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory)). However, this can be done only once per application instance.

Starting with Java 9, there is a more flexible way to provide additional handlers, as mentioned in the following excerpt from the [URL documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URL.html):

> If no URLStreamHandlerFactory has yet been set up, or if the factory's
> createURLStreamHandler method returns null, then the ServiceLoader
> mechanism is used to locate [URLStreamHandlerProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/spi/URLStreamHandlerProvider.html) implementations
> using the system class loader.

So create your own URLStreamHandlerProvider, check its documentation linked above, create a configuration file in your jar file, and your application will then use it, without having to compromise security using `--all-opens`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56088592/13963086) for step-by-step details.

Comment: Yes, Tried this method by calling the static method setURLStreamHandlerFactory, but when I start the wildfly its failing with error factory is already defined. As per Java doc it can be set only once per JVM

Comment: Tried register it during application's startup via 

URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(new CustomURLStreamHandlerFactory());
Note that the Javadoc explicitly says that you can set it at most once.

But when i start wildfly server to bring up the application the custom url handler registration is failing as factory is already defined.

Comment: Tried with  URLStreamHandlerProvider implementation also but that is also not working with wildfly server.