# Scala: How to parse a URL with custom protocols

Tags: scala, url, parse-url

I need to parse URLs that might contain protocols different than `http` or `https`... and since if try to create a `java.net.URL` object with a URL like `nio://localhost:61616` the constructor crashes, I've implemented something like this:

```
def parseURL(spec: String): (String, String, Int, String) = {
  import java.net.URL

  var protocol: String = null

  val url = spec.split("://") match {
    case parts if parts.length > 1 =>
      protocol = parts(0)
      new URL(if (protocol == "http" || protocol == "https" ) spec else "http://" + parts(1))
    case _ => new URL("http" + spec.dropWhile(_ == '/'))
  } 

  var port = url.getPort; if (port < 0) port = url.getDefaultPort
  (protocol, url.getHost, port, url.getFile)
}
```

In case a given URL contains a protocol different than `http` or `https`, I save it in a variable and then I force `http` to let `java.net.URL` parse it without crashing.

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a reason that you cannot use `java.net.URI` instead of `java.net.URL` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406518/why-does-javas-url-class-not-recognize-certain-protocols

Comment: Yes... it works. Thanks, I didn't realize ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use java.net.URI for any non standard protocol.

```
new java.net.URI("nio://localhost:61616").getScheme() // returns nio
```

If you want a more Scala like API, you can check out https://github.com/lemonlabsuk/scala-uri.