# How can I use the Bolt driver with Spring Boot/Data Neo4j

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j-4

I get this error from Spring Boot.

```
Could not deduce driver to use based on URI 'bolt://localhost:7687
```

when attempting to configure with properties, or env variable

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost:7687
```

I did add the driver

```
   <dependency>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I [imagine spring boot doesn't support autoconfiguration for this yet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6690)

How can I set this driver up manually to work with Spring Boot / Data? please provide an example.

Comment: This app seems to show neo4j-ogm + spring boot (though using Groovy), so looks like it's supported. https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-ogm-university/tree/2.0

Comment: @icyrock.com https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-ogm-university/blob/2.0/src/main/resources/ogm.properties looks like it's using http and those aren't spring boot properties, but it might be a way to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current Spring Boot starter for Neo4j does not detect the `bolt` protocol and so cannot autoconfigure the Bolt driver. However, if you supply a Configuration bean in your application context, Spring Boot will use that, and not attempt to autoconfigure the driver itself.

This should be enough to get you going:

```
@Bean
public Configuration getConfiguration() {
   Configuration config = new Configuration();
   config
       .driverConfiguration()
       .setURI("bolt://localhost");
   return config;
}
```

Note that you don't need to declare the driver name in the configuration, it will be autodetected from the URI.

Also, note the `Configuration` class is actually `org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration`, which you'll probably need to use explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

Note that you don't need to declare the driver name in the configuration, it will be autodetected from the URI.

I'm getting '*unknown protocol: bolt*' in this case.

Problem is that `DriverConfiguration.setURI()` will try to instantiate `java.net.URL` to retrieve `userName`, `password` and to set driver. I think it is better to use `java.net.URI` because we don't need to open connection, but only to get info.

Check this post:
[why does java's URL class not recognize certain protocols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406518/why-does-javas-url-class-not-recognize-certain-protocols)